# How can I get this wax effect?

Tags: texturing

[image]

Im trying to make wax on my surfboard model I figured I would do it with a seperate plane shrink wrapped on and the cloud or noise texture, but I cant figure out how to make the black transparent on the noise texture. Any other ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way how to make a pattern transparent:
[image]

Comment: Your a life saver thankyou very much!