# How to put a luma mask on a texture in blender render

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I don't like using cycles, so I prefer using Blender Render.

I have two images for textures. One is the texture itself and the other is a matte.

Texture:[image]   Matte:[image]

How can I combine them to create a transparent (luma mask) texture of any mesh?

Please ask if you need any more information

Comment: In the texture panel you can assign different images as texture fill and texture mask. Its pretty old way to do it so you may be challenged getting an accurate description. Your material must have transparency active so it can grab the texture mask value for alpha

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131632/how-can-i-get-this-wax-effect/131634#131634